# How to use harpoon-style arrows over vectors, like this?

Tags: arrows, vector

How do I typeset harpoon arrows that look like this in LaTeX?

[image]

I've tried the `harpoon` package's `\overrightharpoon` feature, but its arrowhead is too big/prominent... I'm hoping for something that looks more normal, like in the screenshot above.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10):

You could use `\rightharpoonup` and `\overset` (which needs the `amsmath` package). Because 
`\overset{\rightharpoonup}` is quite long, I would define a newcommand, like so:

```
\newcommand{\harpoon}{\overset{\rightharpoonup}}
```

Only the space above seems a little bit unpleasant. But it works just fine.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\harpoon}{\overset{\rightharpoonup}}

\begin{document}
\[
\Delta \overset{\rightharpoonup} L = 
    \harpoon L_2 - \harpoon L_1 = \harpoon 0 
\]
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the space above is definitely unpleasant, so I won't be using it. +1 for the answer though.