# Extracting overrightharpoon from MnSymbol

Tags: accents, mnsymbol

Many previous questions have talked about extracting symbols from MnSymbol, or found alternatives from other packages. However, I have not been able to find a suitable replacement for `\overrightharpoon` that is in MnSymbol. Indeed, is there a nicer replacement for symbols of this type? It does not appear in any of the earlier summaries and questions.

Bonus: If you could be so nice as to include another symbol with harpoon style tick, but now with a backwards 4 tick (so that `\overrightharpoon` is a 3-vector, and the new symbol is a 4-vector, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do either of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242115/32374 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98155/32374 help?

Comment: I'm not posting an answer, because I'm not sure I fully understand the question. However, the actual horizontal harpoon glyphs from MnSymbol are in MnSymbolA, glyphs 64, 66, 72, 74.  To turn them into oversets, once importing them, one could use, for example, `\mathaccent`, though the overset glyph tends to be wider than the letter.

Comment: @darthbith, The first link sends back here. The 2nd link has it too tall, as the original question poster noted, and is thus unusable. 

@StevenB.Segletes, I wanted to extract them out, but there is `\overarrow`, `\arrowfill` and more, that are undefined. Also, I do not know where the glyphs are supposed to be -- presumably I should be able to use the glyphs predefined in standard LaTeX, for all of them that I need were already predefined, but when I consulted the MnSymbol package documentation, it lists it after the F glyph bits, so I do not see why I should be importing A glyphs.

Comment: @user77509 Sorry, first link was meant to be this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96141/32374 (which is the duplicate linked from the second link I posted earlier) :-)

Comment: @darthbith, I tried everything that I could have searched before. In fact, since the MnSymbol `\uprightharpoon` character had been extracted by Steven, I have retried it with that too, but it is still too high, and most importantly, fails to scale. Scaling is necessary. You might want to check the test case I added as part of Steven's answer.

Comment: See here: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764) You may have a different question, but it seems like you've felt comfortable enough to accept a similar solution.

Comment: @Werner, I have already used that. It did not work, but egreg has already given the answer I wanted -- I simply did not extract one more symbol that I could not have known beforehand. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user77509: For future reference, please mention what you have tried. And don't say "it doesn't work". If the ultimate solution seems to replicate another answer, then it seems like you something must have gone wrong in your attempt. Showing this would help you in the future.

Comment: @Werner, ah, yes, thanks. I did not know that my starting statement referencing "Many previous questions" was not sufficient. Mea culpa. The solution by egreg is _fundamentally_ different from the solutions other people have accepted, and actually should be added to those other questions, as being the necessary addendum to complete them. Especially the summary thread that includes all the extensible arrows. That was a brilliant solution.

Comment: @Werner, the appropriate questions that are most related to this question, that would benefit from the answer egreg supplied, are these: 
[Extensible \vec instead of \overrightarrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114321/extensible-vec-instead-of-overrightarrow) and 
[Configurable and Extensible Accents (Arrows, Dots, Vectors)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208162/configurable-and-extensible-accents-arrows-dots-vectors)
If you know how this question could be collapsed onto them, it would be best.

Comment: @user77509: Since you've supplied these questions in the comment thread, they are now linked (you'll see them in the right bar). That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the harpoons and also the relation bar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolA5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolA6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolA7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolA8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12->   MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolA-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolA-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolA-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolA-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyA}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\overleftharpoon}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\leftharpoonfill@}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\overrightharpoon}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\rightharpoonfill@}}
\def\leftharpoonfill@{\arrowfill@\leftharpoondown\mn@relbar\mn@relbar}
\def\rightharpoonfill@{\arrowfill@\mn@relbar\mn@relbar\rightharpoonup}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoondown}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{'112}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoonup}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{'100}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mn@relbar}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{'320}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\overrightharpoon{abc}$
$\overleftharpoon{abc}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh beautiful, my students will love you. I have eliminated the definitions of left and right harpoon fills by unrolling them into the definitions referencing them, since they are only used once. `...\overarrow@{\arrowfill...}}}` Also, I did not require the import of glyphs 112 and 100, just 320. 

Now, just to find the correct replacement for 4-vectors. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

REWORKED based on comments from the OP, to provide extensibility.

It is based on my answer at [Extensible \vec instead of \overrightarrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114321/extensible-vec-instead-of-overrightarrow/140550#140550)

Here, I use the default harpoon to provide extensibility.  Method can be extended to other harpoon varieties.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\shlength
\newcommand\xshlonghvecr[2][1]{\setlength\shlength{#1pt}%
  \stackengine{-1.0pt}{$#2$}{\smash{$\kern\shlength%
    \stackengine{2.75pt}{$\mathchar"012A$}%
      {\rule{\widthof{$#2$}}{.50pt}\kern1pt}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}\kern-\shlength$}}%
      {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\newcommand\xshlonghvecl[2][1]{\setlength\shlength{#1pt}%
  \stackengine{-1.0pt}{$#2$}{\smash{$\kern\shlength%
    \stackengine{2.75pt}{\kern-1pt$\mathchar"0128$}%
      {\rule{\widthof{$#2$}}{.50pt}\kern1pt}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}\kern-\shlength$}}%
      {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\[ \vec{A} \quad \xshlonghvecr{ABC} \quad \xshlonghvecr{xy}
 \quad \xshlonghvecr{x} \]
\[ \vec{A} \quad \xshlonghvecl{ABC} \quad \xshlonghvecl{xy}
 \quad \xshlonghvecl{x} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, you do not even need to extract those glyphs. `\rightharpoonup` is almost exactly the same as `\uprightharpoon`, though the latter is slightly bigger. (Which would be good -- when I replaced your option with `\rightharpoonup`, it is too small. Also, both could use some increase in size.)

But in any case, your solution does not scale, and is also much too high. Have you tried `\overrightharpoon` as MnSymbol defines it? It can be rather beautiful. My `\vec` is renewed to use `\overrightharpoon`.

If you wish to test, try `\overrightharpoon{ \mathrm{d}^3 r }`

Comment: @user77509  I noted that in my commentary.  I showed the glyph extraction, just because you seemed particularly interested in the MnSymbol version for some reason.

Comment: the glyph extraction I was interested in, is in the accent lengthening part. The `\uprightharpoon` is an interesting addition for me, but not what I wanted. 

Surely, there is a precomputed accent lengthening engine that can combine parts. I already know of that system that could do, left parts, lengthening middle, and then right parts. Yet, I could not get it to work. Sigh.

Comment: I am sorry that I do not have enough reputation points to give you some upvotes.

Comment: @user77509 I had to depart for a period, but I will give additional thought on the issue of extensibility.

Comment: it is already solved. See egreg's solution. No need to waste your time any longer.

Comment: @user77509 True, but I wanted to give at least an alternative that worked as you wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand the question (is it a question of fonts or arrows?), but if you're only look for `\rightharpoonup` and `\leftharpoonup` macros, I wrote a the [overarrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overarrows) package which redefine them (and other variants).

As example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[overleftharpoonup, overrightharpoonup]{overarrows}

\begin{document}

  \[ \overrightharpoonup{abc} \]

  \[ \overleftharpoonup{abc} \]

  \bigskip

  \TestOverArrow{overleftharpoonup}

  \medskip

  \TestOverArrow{overrightharpoonup}

\end{document}
```

which gives (`\TestOverArrow` is a test macro defined by the `overarrows` package):
[image: \overleftharpoonup and \overrightharpoonup from the overarrows package]

If you want symbols from MnSymbol, you can redefine `leftharpoonup` and `rightharpoonup` like in egreg's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
<-6>  MnSymbolA5
<6-7>  MnSymbolA6
<7-8>  MnSymbolA7
<8-9>  MnSymbolA8
<9-10> MnSymbolA9
<10-12> MnSymbolA10
<12->   MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
<-6>  MnSymbolA-Bold5
<6-7>  MnSymbolA-Bold6
<7-8>  MnSymbolA-Bold7
<8-9>  MnSymbolA-Bold8
<9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
<10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
<12->   MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyA}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoonup}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{'112}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoonup}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{'100}

\usepackage[overleftharpoonup, overrightharpoonup]{overarrows}

\begin{document}

\[ \overrightharpoonup{abc} \]

\[ \overleftharpoonup{abc} \]

\bigskip

\TestOverArrow{overleftharpoonup}

\medskip

\TestOverArrow{overrightharpoonup}

\end{document}
```

or simply add

```tex
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

Both give:
[image: overharpoons with MnSymbol]

Comment: Hi there; this is many years old and as the comments have made clear, I have been using egreg's solution in all my LaTeX code for... hmm, almost a decade now. Your answer is a lot shorter, though. Thanks.