# Special vector over text (half head of the arrow, vertically compact)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm looking for a vector symbol that look like that

[image]

and has the following characteristic:

1. is meant to be for maths environment (also inline)
2. has the form `\commandname{body}`
3. is exactly wide as the body (to avoid problem with indices pre or post-fixed)
4. the arrow is as this one: [image]...
5. ... but only the upper half
6. vertically compact enough to be inline.
7. compatible with `amsmath`
8. **expression under the arrow is to consist of more than one character** and the arrow should cover the whole expression

There are many solutions out there that cover only half of my problem. The best starting point is the package `esvect` from where I took the picture of the arrow:
http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/esvect/esvect.pdf
It also contains the whole code (for who understand it).
What is missing in the package `esvect` is that the arrow should be halved.

MWE, the `\myvect` is to be replaced

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\myvect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\myvect{r}$
\end{document}
```

Here is anorther link
[How to use harpoon-style arrows over vectors, like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98155/how-to-use-harpoon-style-arrows-over-vectors-like-this)
BUT (1) the space between body and arrow is for me not acceptable (as pointed out by a comment) (2) I really do not like the type of arrow head.

Comment: If the expression under the arrow is to consist of more than one character, please say so.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extensible arrow can be easily obtained by copying the definitions in `amsmath`. As for the form of the tip, the problem is to find an adequate font. The `mathabx` package provides something more similar to the `esvect` arrows, thought it's still no perfect match. Since `mathabx` replaces a lot of symbols, one may decide to import only one, see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/82917).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% \overarrow@ and \arrowfill@ are defined in amsmath
\newcommand*{\overrightharpoonup}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\rightharpoonupfill@}}
\newcommand*{\rightharpoonupfill@}{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightharpoonup}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightharpoonup}{3}{matha}{"E1}

\begin{document}

$\overrightharpoonup{a}$
$\overrightharpoonup{ab}$
$\overrightharpoonup{abcde}$

\bigskip
% using the mathabx harpoon
\let\rightharpoonup\varrightharpoonup
$\overrightharpoonup{a}$
$\overrightharpoonup{ab}$
$\overrightharpoonup{abcde}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second line is very good. One point: is it possible to integrate the trick of @Sebastiano in order to diminish the gap between arrow and text?

Comment: I also notice that the arrow, in case of a single char, is ways wider than the char. But perhaps that is defined in amsmath.

Comment: @PeptideChain The minimal length is the the width of `\rightharpoonup` and there is not much to do about that. One could start clipping characters but that would become too hacky for my taste. The height might be adjustable but I can't do it right now. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: If by "adjusting the height" you mean to scale vertically, then the head of the arrow get reduced, and that would be not good. Just intuitively since I have no much idea: instead of clipping isn't it possible to move the arrow vertically (like a negative distance)? Take your time: I have implemented you solution and if you improve it, I'll adjust the macro. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeptideChain No, by adjusting the height I meant reducing the gap between the arrow and the symbol(s).

Comment: I would love this for the backwardharpoonup as well!

Answer (score 2):

Bad notation, IMHO. Anyway

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}
\newcommand{\myvect}[1]{\accentset{\rightharpoonup}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\myvect{r}$
\end{document}
```

does what you want.

[image]

Comment: (1) bad notation: in general I agree; it is only the geometrical field, over two points like PQ, otherwise I use boldface (physics) or nothing (linear algebra); perhaps I will use just the order of the points to determine the direction; (2) about your solution: (a) the figure of the head is not correct, (b) the arrows does not cover the whole width of the body (try $\myvect{AB}$)

Answer (score 2):

I agree totally with the user @egreg. If you prefer it is possible to use a macro on the [site](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=3cz1) (it has added into the code) where you can increase or decrease the height of the `\rightharpoonup` symbol at your convenience. If you set with `\kern0` you have a good blank space between the symbol and the character.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%% Edit (\kern0) of the specific macro from https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=3cz1
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ovset}[3][0ex]{%
  \mathrel{\mathop{#3}\limits^{
    \vbox to#1{\kern0\ex@
    \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\vss}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\ovset{\rightharpoonup}{r}, \ovset{\rightharpoonup}{P}$

\end{document}
```

**Addendum**: Using `mathabx` package you have a similar picture of the arrow. Peraphs using `trimclip`, o `clipbox` you can obtain a exact symbol.
Here there is an addendum.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathabx}
%%%% Edit (\kern0) of the specific macro from https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=3cz1
        \makeatletter
        \newcommand{\ovset}[3][0ex]{%
          \mathrel{\mathop{#3}\limits^{
            \vbox to#1{\kern0\ex@
            \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\vss}}}}
        \makeatother

\begin{document}

$\ovset{\rightharpoonup}{r}, \quad \ovset{\rightharpoonup}{G}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is an improvement compared to @egreg; as in the comment to @egreg : (a) the figure of the head is not correct, (b) the arrows does not cover the whole width of the body

Comment: :-) But I have not understood the question (a) and (b) excuse me. Can you put an image done with your hand, please?

Comment: I added a picture to my question. (a) With "head" I mean the head of the arrow; the form of the head is not correct (b) Both solutions produce an arrow that is too short and not as long as the text under the arrow is. The solution is not far away from the package esvect